# CStringArray common denominator of list elements?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Given a list of array elements in a CStringArray:

```
dog
dog 
cat 
cat
cat
cat
mice
```

I would like to find the common elements:(  dog, cat, mice ) within CStringArray.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array to put all the like elements together, then step through it and each time the element changes copy it to your output.

Comment: So no method in CStringArray will find the common elements? I thought one existed but I can't find it...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and use the value of element as a hash key, set the key-value pair (the actual value is not relevant here) in a hash table.

Then you get a set of all the hash keys as the result.

Maybe `std::set` and `std::unique` should be considered as well.